# Top part of a tableView specific color even if refreshing

Tags: xcode, tableview

I've run into a simple problem, that I can not solve even after looking everywhere..

---

I made a grey table view, and at the top I have a cell with white background.
Is it possible to whenever the user refreshes, make it also white (on the top)?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
     let refresh = UIRefreshControl()

       let backgroundColor = UIColor.red

        refresh.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
        refresh.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.refreshs), for: .valueChanged)
        tableView.addSubview(refresh)


        var frame = tableView.bounds
        frame.origin.y = -frame.size.height
        let backgroundView = UIView(frame: frame)
        backgroundView.autoresizingMask = .flexibleWidth
        backgroundView.backgroundColor = backgroundColor // background color pull to refresh 

        tableView.insertSubview(backgroundView, at: 0)
```